# NodeJS server iOS push notification, where to store deviceTokens?

Tags: node.js, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement iOS push notification connected to a Node.JS server. I don't know what are best-practices to do it. As I was thinking to make an endpoint which will be called when user opens the app and store on server as a dictionary of [ key  userID : value deviceToken ], I am not sure where on server should I store this dictionary. Therefore when I need to send a push notification to a user, I will know how to find it dictionary[userId] would give me back the deviceToken. Although I think I should implement it in the login endpoint, as a user can login using different phones. Can you help me please with suggestions how to implement this. Thank you so much .

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("token: \(token)")
        // call API for adding token to dictionary: [ userId : token]
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your problem: When you user logs in, you are talking to a  server to validate the credentials and that server sends you back a token, if the authentication is successful. Your question is: Where do I store the token?

Comment: @rs7 no,  in order to send a notification through iOS push notification I need the deviceToken which is a different token compared to the token given by the server when auth is successful. deviceToken is used by the server to send the notification. 

apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then( (result) => {
 
});

Comment: @rs7
My problems are: 1)when is the right moment to send the deviceToken in my iOS app
2) Where to store those token on my server ( I was thinking to store it n server in a dictionary where key is the userID and the value is deviceToken) . So every time I send a notification to a certain user, I can fin inside dictionary[userId] and use it. But I don't know if this is a good idea. Thank you

Comment: I'm not super well versed on the subject, but I would say that it depends on your application - does the dictionary need to be secured? If that's the case, use an encryption mechanism. With regards to 1) you could send the token when the user registers an account, that way all users will have a token associated with their user ID.

Comment: @rs7 yes, but if the user logs in using other device than the one he signed up the push notification would go to the wrong device. Looks like best is to override the value associated with his userId every time when he logs in, in this way that situation is avoided.

Comment: If your app is cross-platform, I would keep maintain a dictionary with arrays of device tokens as values. Everytime the user logs in (that includes when the user registers), you want to append a device token if that token doesn't already exist in the array.